# JPA with TopLink: No META-INF/persistence.xml was found in classpath

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, classpath, toplink

```
public class LoginTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("IRCBotPU");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    em.getTransaction().begin();

    Login lg = new Login();
    lg.setPassword("password");
    lg.setUserName("Rocky");

    em.persist(lg);
    em.flush();

    Login st = em.find(Login.class, lg.getPassword());
    System.out.println(st);

    em.getTransaction().commit();

    em.close();
    emf.close();

}
}
```

I'm getting an Exception when I try to run this class

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named IRCBotPU:  
   No META-INF/persistence.xml was found in classpath.
```

META-INF/persistence.xml is in my classpath. I don't know what is the reason or this exception.

Persistence library is TopLink.

Comment: @oxbow_lakes - You could have fixed it :-) I just did.

Answer (score 23):

I had the same problem, i was keeping my persistence.xml file in the WebContent/META-INF directory, while the jpa specification says:
 **the root of the persistence unit is the WEB-INF/classes directory; the persistence.xml file is therefore contained in the WEB-INF/classes/META-INF directory**

try placing persistence.xml under src/META-INF.

Comment: in the eclipse following worked for me: src/META-INF/persistence.xml

Answer (score 3):

if you are using `IntelliJ` or a maven project structure you need to place the entire `"META-INF/persistence.xml"` file in the in resources(src/resources) folder so that it will move your `persistence.xml` file into `"WEB-INF/classes/persistence.xml"` location.

if you are using `eclipse` or something else makes the changes accordingly so that it will move the file to `WEB-INF/classes/persistence.xml`

anything else did not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

The error is somewhat misleading.  the XML file itself should **not** be in the classpath;  the part of the message saying "META-INF/persistence.xml" means that the directory containing META-INF/persistence.xml **should** be.

If your hard drive had the following

C:\libs\JPA\META-INF\Persistence.xml

then your classpath should include this

```
CLASSPATH=c:\libs\JPA
```

If META-INF\Persistence.xml were contained in foo.jar, assuming META-INF/Persistence.xml were located on the root folder of the jar, your classpath should have this

```
CLASSPATH=C:\<path to jar>\foo.jar
```

This may seem obvious or redundant but my goal is to make sure we're comparing apples to apples and the CLASSPATH, along with classloading, can be a bugger to deal with.

So, can you post your CLASSPATH?

Comment: My classpath is set to the exact way that you have mentioned above.But it still won't work.

Comment: Is the Jar that contains the implementation of "IRCBotPU" in the classpath?

Answer (score 1):

`persistence.xml` should not be in your classpath; JAR file that contains `persistence.xml` in its META-INF folder should.

Comment: What is the name of the JAR that contains a META-INF/persistence.xml?  Is said JAR in your apps CLASSPATH?

Comment: No it's not a JAR file I'm using NetBeans 6.0 so it just creates the package META-INF and inside it persistence.xml.

Answer (score 1):

i have a web application and the following worked fine. What i did was add the META-INF directory with the persistence.xml into the src/main/resources location [Maven project]

Answer (score 0):

Your META-INF/persistence.xml file should look something like this:

```
// <persistence>
//   <persistence-unit name="IRCBotPU">
//     <provider>oracle.toplink.essentials.ejb.cmp3.EntityManagerFactoryProvider</provider>
//     <!-- All persistence classes must be listed -->
//     <class>entity.Customer</class>
//     <class>entity.Order</class>
//     <class>entity.Item</class>
//     <properties>
//       <!-- Provider-specific connection properties -->
//       <property name="toplink.jdbc.driver" value="<database driver>"/>
//       <property name="toplink.jdbc.url" value="<database url>"/>
//       <property name="toplink.jdbc.user" value="<user>"/>
//       <property name="toplink.jdbc.password" value="<password>"/>
//       <!-- Provider-specific settings -->
//       <property name="toplink.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
//     </properties>
//   </persistence-unit>
// </persistence>
```

Your persistence-unit's name attribute in your persistence.xml doesn't match the value you're passing into the Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory method.  Make sure that your persistence-unit name is set to "IRCBotPU".

Answer (score 0):

I created a folder callled META-INF under src and it works. "marcosbeirigo" answered it already. I do not know why I have to put that persistance.xml in there though. I put it under WebContent/META-INF and did not work

Comment: Because src is on the classpath, that is why it worked.