# What are the correct security policy value settings to allow both RMI and JPA/Hibernate to work at the same time

Tags: java, jpa, security-policy

I'm working on an application that requires the use of both JPA/Hibernate and RMI. Since RMI requires the use of a Security Policy to make sure that access to the network is correctly assigned I also now have to worry about the folder permissions.

I've been looking online (and here at SO) for a couple of days now trying to find a solution to this problem. Basically the problem is that for JPA/Hibernate to work I have to place the `persistence.xml` file in the `META-INF` directory, and the `META-INF` directory must be under the `src` directory of my project (which doesn't make sense to me either but it works). So that the project layout is basically:

```
 org.project.root
 |
 |>src
 |  |
 |  |>org.project.package
 |  |
 |  |>META-INF
 |       |
 |       |>persistence.xml
 |
 |>config
 |
 |>database
 |
 |>logs
```

My security policy file I've been trying to grant read access to the folder `${user.dir}${/}src${/}META-INF${/}-`, however, when I try to run the application I get the error `No Persistence provider for EntityManager named DERBY_ACPSTORE_CREATE`. My persistence.xml file however does contain this, and it works when comment out all the RMI stuff and stop reading the security policy. So my question is how can I get my security policy file to allow me to read the persistence.xml file?

**UPDATE 1**

Using the suggested path information from @Vineet Reynolds I'm able to see the file's path using:

```
 File f = new File("META-INF/persistence.xml");
 System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

However, I'm still getting this error when I'm trying to create the database.

```
 javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named DERBY_ACPSTORE_CREATE
 at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
      at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:33)
      at org.myproject.data.DBInit.dbInit(DBInit.java:29)
      at org.myproject.ACPStoreMainService.main(ACPStoreMainService.java:91)
```

My persistence.xml as I said worked fine before I started using the security policy so I know that the persistence-unit "DERBY_ACPSTORE_CREATE" is present and correct.

**Update 2**

Although I'm not sure what good this is since it worked when I don't use the Security Policy here's my persistence.xml contents:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
      <persistence-unit name="DERBY_ACPSTORE_CREATE">
           <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider
           <class>org.myproject.data.MessageHistory</class>
           <properties>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" 
           value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
                <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:derby:database/acpstore;create=true" />
                <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
                <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
                <property name="use_sql_comments" value="true" />
                <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="user" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password" />
           </properties>
      </persistence-unit>
 </persistence>
```

**UPDATE 3**

As I mentioned in the comment to the answer from Vineet Reynolds below I've tested the persistence.xml without the security and it is now working. Then when I reinstate the security policy then I get the errors again. As such below is the contents of my security policy and how I create the security in my application:

```
 grant {
      permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "shutdownHooks";
      permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "readFileDescriptor";
      permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "writeFileDescriptor";
      permission java.util.PropertyPermission "user.dir", "read";
      permission java.net.SocketPermission "172.10.10.21:1024-65535", "connect, accept, resolve";
      permission java.net.SocketPermission "172.10.10.21:1-1023", "connect,resolve";
      permission java.io.FilePermission "${user.dir}${/}META-INF${/}-", "read";
      permission java.io.FilePermission "${user.dir}${/}config${/}-", "read, write, delete";
      permission java.io.FilePermission "${user.dir}${/}database${/}-", "read, write, delete";
 };
```

And this is what happens in my application to set the security manager

```
 if(System.getSecurityManager() == null)
 {
      System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
 }
```

**UPDATE 4**

I've found a message that I didn't notice before coming from log4j. The message is

```
 [main] INFO org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration  - Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath
```

which seems odd to me. So I listed the directories in the classpath and I found `org.project.root\bin` but not `org.project.root`. I know now that the META-INF in the runtime is located as `org.project.root\META-INF`, and that the classpath should point to the `org.project.root` so that JPA and hibernate can access find the persistence.xml. So would could it be that I need to somehow change the classpath to match this?

Comment: It looks like I've brought my question to the same point as this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279060/jpa-with-toplink-no-meta-inf-persistence-xml-was-found-in-classpath but the question there doesn't seem to have an accepted answer, nor one that I've not checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give Vineet a up vote for helping me with knowing where the META-INF folder ends up, however, I finally figured out what my permissions problem is.

The `java.io.FilePermission` is hierarchical, meaning you have to give "read" access to higher folders before you can give it to lower directories.

Basically in my security policy file I should have done `permission java.io.FilePermission "${user.dir}${/}-", "read";` first before I entered `permission java.io.FilePermission "${user.dir}${/}META-INF${/}-", "read";`

Answer (score 1):

The original question does not indicate if the `src` directory is present in the runtime environment or not. I would assume that it is not present in the runtime environment, for reasons stated below.

The `src` directory is an artifact that is usually required during development to represent the source directory. At runtime, this directory is usually not present in the directory structure (of a JAR file).

You might be better off specifying the permission as one to grant read access to:

```
${user.dir}${/}META-INF${/}-
```

**Edit:**

Based on the fact that no SecurityExceptions are thrown, and that a PersistenceExcpetion is thrown, it appears that the contents of the persistence.xml might be invalid. The following questions at StackOverflow could be referenced, but the resolution need not be exactly the same as depicted in the answers.

1. [javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named customerManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739387/javax-persistence-persistenceexception-no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager)
2. [No Persistence provider for EntityManager named …](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158159/no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager-named)

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. However, I tried the permission path you recommended but it still didn't work.

Comment: @JRSofty, you might want to post the directory structure of the deployed artifact, (instead of the development environment). Additionally, posting any stacktraces encountered especially ones involving `SecurityExceptions` would help. There might be more permissions required than you have anticipated.

Comment: I've added the only stacktrace that appears during this problem. As well as some more information that tells me that you were right about the META-INF in the runtime being outside the `src` directory. Problem still exists though.

Comment: @JRSofty, you might want to check the updated answer. It would help if you could post the contents of persistence.xml as well.

Comment: I've posted the contents of persistence.xml. The two links that you provided I've already reviewed and as I mentioned before this persistence.xml worked before the addition of the security policy.

Comment: @vineet-reynolds After taking a look at my persistence.xml I did find some errors. I've since fixed them, removed the security policy portion of the application, and ran it. No problems all is as expected. Re-instated the security policy, and once again the same error is shown. So there must be some sort of inconsistency between the Security Manager and the persistence.xml. I will update again with contents of SecurityPolicy.

Comment: @JRSofty, having knowledge of what happens when a JPA Provider is looked up by the SPI mechanism, I strongly feel that a SecurityException is occuring, but is not getting conveyed. You might want to verify if the logger is reporting SecurityExceptions. If that is a false positive, you might want to debug the JPA Provider's loading mechanism, using the logs.

Comment: I think I might have found the problem. I'm finding a message that hibernate cannot find the META-INF in the classpath. I checked my classpath and the path for `org.myproject.root\bin` is there but not `org.myproject.root` where the META-INF is located. It might be that I need to make changes to the classpath to get this to work.

Comment: @JRSofty, JPA & Hibernate would require not only the persistence.xml file, but also a `META-INF/services/javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider`. The latter is usually provided by Hibernate in one of it's JARs.

Comment: I've never used a META-`INF/services/javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider` before and have had everything working, unless this is located inside a jar with the persistence libraries that I use.